# TI ROTS BIOS setting semaphore() function error

Tags: rtos

I keep getting an error when I run the code below.
This is supposed to be an example code so I am not sure why this code is getting this error.

It has something to do with semaphore() but I honestly have no idea where this error comes from.
Could anyone help me out?

[image: Error image]

[image: BIOS/SYS setting 1]

[image: BIOS/SYS setting 2]

[image: BIOS/SYS setting 3]

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
#10010 errors encountered during linking; "blink_target_HWI.out" not built  blink_target_HWI            C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
#10234-D  unresolved symbols remain   blink_target_HWI            C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
gmake: *** [all] Error 2    blink_target_HWI            C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
gmake[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJDOZ.png): *** [blink_target_HWI.out] Error 1    blink_target_HWI            C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
unresolved symbol semaphore, first referenced in ./main.obj blink_target_HWI            C/C++ Problem

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Project: Blink TM4C BIOS Using Hwi (STARTER)
// Author: Eric Wilbur
// Date: June 2014
//
// Note: The function call TimerIntClear(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT) HAS
//       to be in the ISR. This fxn clears the TIMER's interrupt flag coming
//       from the peripheral - it does NOT clear the CPU interrupt flag - that
//       is done by hardware. The author struggled figuring this part out - hence
//       the note. And, in the Swi lab, this fxn must be placed in the
//       Timer_ISR fxn because it will be the new ISR.
//
// Follow these steps to create this project in CCSv6.0:
// 1. Project -> New CCS Project
// 2. Select Template:
//    - TI-RTOS for Tiva-C -> Driver Examples -> EK-TM4C123 LP -> Example Projects ->
//      Empty Project
//    - Empty Project contains full instrumentation (UIA, RTOS Analyzer) and
//      paths set up for the TI-RTOS version of MSP430Ware
// 3. Delete the following files:
//    - Board.h, empty.c, EK_TM4C123GXL.c/h, empty_readme.txt
// 4. Add main.c from TI-RTOS Workshop Solution file for this lab
// 5. Edit empty.cfg as needed (to add/subtract) BIOS services, delete given Task
// 6. Build, load, run...
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//----------------------------------------
// BIOS header files
//----------------------------------------
#include <xdc/std.h>                        //mandatory - have to include first, for BIOS types
#include <ti/sysbios/BIOS.h>                //mandatory - if you call APIs like BIOS_start()
#include <xdc/runtime/Log.h>                //needed for any Log_info() call
#include <xdc/cfg/global.h>                 //header file for statically defined objects/handles


//------------------------------------------
// TivaWare Header Files
//------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "driverlib/timer.h"


//----------------------------------------
// Prototypes
//----------------------------------------
void hardware_init(void);
void ledToggle(void);
void delay(void);
void blink_target_swi(void);

//---------------------------------------
// Globals
//---------------------------------------
volatile int16_t i16ToggleCount = 0;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main()
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
{

   hardware_init();                         // init hardware via Xware
   BIOS_start();

}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// hardware_init()
//
// inits GPIO pins for toggling the LED
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void hardware_init(void)
{
    uint32_t ui32Period;

    //Set CPU Clock to 40MHz. 400MHz PLL/2 = 200 DIV 5 = 40MHz
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);

    // ADD Tiva-C GPIO setup - enables port, sets pins 1-3 (RGB) pins for output
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3);

    // Turn on the LED
    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 4);

    // Timer 2 setup code
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_TIMER2);           // enable Timer 2 periph clks
    TimerConfigure(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_CFG_PERIODIC);        // cfg Timer 2 mode - periodic

    ui32Period = (SysCtlClockGet() /2);                     // period = CPU clk div 2 (500ms)
    TimerLoadSet(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_A, ui32Period);         // set Timer 2 period

    TimerIntEnable(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT);        // enables Timer 2 to interrupt CPU

    TimerEnable(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_A);                      // enable Timer 2

}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ledToggle()
//
// toggles LED on Tiva-C LaunchPad
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ledToggle(void)
{
    //TimerIntClear(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT);

    // LED values - 2=RED, 4=BLUE, 8=GREEN
    while(1){

    Semaphore_pend(semaphore(),BIOS_WAIT_FOREVER);
    if(GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2))
    {
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, 2);
    }

    //delay();                                              // create a delay of ~1/2sec

    i16ToggleCount += 1;                                    // keep track of #toggles

    Log_info1("LED TOGGLED [%u] TIMES",i16ToggleCount);     // send toggle count to UIA
    };
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// delay()
//
// Creates a 500ms delay via TivaWare fxn
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void delay(void)
{
     SysCtlDelay(6700000);      // creates ~500ms delay - TivaWare fxn
}

void blink_target_swi(void)     // Software driven interrupt
{
   Semaphore_post(semaphore());
   //Swi_post(blink_target_SWI);
   TimerIntClear(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT);         // must clear timer flag FROM timer
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that SYS/BIOS tool, but I'm guessing that you used the tool to define `semaphore0` and then misspelled it in your code.  Try replacing `semaphore()` with `semaphore0` (in two places, at least).

Comment: Somewhere in your IDE there must be a plain-text report of teh build output, post that rather then a picture of the "Problems" window with its truncated diagnostics and lack of file an line number information.